# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined reactjs when i have declared the property already

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

Hi I am running the following , I have set textfield property to a string and as far as I know thats an array and map functions should work on arrays but it still says Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, well Is it not defined in there in the state? Thanks

```
class App extends Component {

  state={
    textfield:"first value", 
  }

makeUnique =(textfield)=>{
  return String.prototype.concat(...new Set(textfield) );
}

  textchanged = (event)=>{
    this.setState({
      textfield:event.target.value,
      caltexlength:event.target.value.length,    
    })    
  }


  render() {
    let uniquechars=null;

    uniquechars=(<div>
      {
        this.textfield.map((char,index)=>{
          return <charComponent
          char ={this.makeUnique(this.state.textfield)}/>
        })
      }
    </div>)## Heading ##
```

Comment: TextField is a string so why are you doing map on it. Map works only on arrays. To access state TextField it should be this.state.textField but not this.textField

Comment: thanks @HemadriDasari I have tried that it says  this.state.textfield.map is not a function,? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn’t do map on it as I told you map works only on array but not on strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the line `this.textfield.map((char,index)` as below.

```
[...this.state.textfield].map((char,index)
```

With the spread operator you will create an array from your string and you can call map on it.

Comment: till now, i was thinking that textfield was basicallly an array but its not its an array if we put textfield.split('')

Comment: textfield is a string and here we use the spread operator to spread the string and create an array of chars. This is a common practice in redux reducers for immutability of state, creating a new array using the prev state and new data. So you don't need to use textfield.split('').

Comment: Make sense - some  work on strings and some doesn’t , and spread operator works both on strings and arrays equally .

Comment: Yes it is. When you want to create an immutable array, spread operator is the way to go. Especially when your state is an array, you have to pass a newly created array to setState using this. Have you solved your problem then?

Comment: Great to hear that Naveen. If this helped, please make sure to mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

TextField is a string so why are you doing map on it. Map works only on arrays. To access state TextField it should be this.state.textField but not this.textField

So change

```
uniquechars=(<div>
  {
    this.textfield.map((char,index)=>{
      return <charComponent
      char ={this.makeUnique(this.state.textfield)}/>
    })
  }
</div>)
```

To

```
uniquechars=(<div>
   <charComponent
      char ={this.makeUnique(this.state.textfield)}/>
</div>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace

```
this.textfield.map
```

to

```
this.state.textfield.split('').map
```